# Angular service variable updated value not reflected in component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-services, angular-route-guards

I am facing issues while accessing the service variable values inside my angular component.
Navbar component is setting user as logged in inside the service and routing guard is responsible for enabling children route, but routing guard is not able to fetch the updated value of userStatus

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserDetailsService } from '../user-details.service.js';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  UserStatus: boolean;

  constructor( private UserService: UserDetailsService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.UserService.UserStatus.subscribe((data: boolean) => {
      this.UserStatus = data;
    });
    this.UserService.getUserStatus();
  }
  logout() {
    this.UserService.UpdateStatus(false);
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
  login() {
    this.UserService.UpdateStatus(true);
    this.router.navigate(['home/products']);
  }
}
```

Routing Guard Component

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, CanActivateChild} from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserDetailsService } from './user-details.service.js';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginGuardGuard implements CanActivateChild, CanActivate {
  constructor(private userDetails: UserDetailsService, private router: Router) {}
  canActivateChild(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if (this.userDetails.getUserStatus()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        // return false;
      }
  }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
      if (this.userDetails.getUserStatus()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
        return false;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: surely, will keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in your `app-navbar` and `route-guard` component, you have imported your service with a `js` extension which is against the singleton model of services inside angular.

Because of the .js extension, the transpiler is identifying them as two separate instances.

So changing the imports from

```
import { UserDetailsService } from '../user-details.service.js';
```

to

```
import { UserDetailsService } from '../user-details.service';
```

should fix the issue.

Comment: This fixed the issue, i think while importing with vsc it got included by itself
Anyways, Thanks for Support and instant reply